# Binding to models in an ArrayProxy

Tags: ember.js

I have 6 'page' objects held in an 'pages' ArrayProxy object.

I have a StateManager instance that will regulate the 6 views corresponding to these 6 'page' objects.

```
App.stateManager = Ember.StateManager.create({
  rootElement: '.tab-content',
  initialState: 'firstTab',
  firstTab: Ember.ViewState.create({
    view: Ember.View.extend({
      templateName: 'first',
      contentBinding: 'App.tempObject'// binding to a regular Ember Object works.
    })
  }),
  secondTab: Ember.ViewState.create({
    view: Ember.View.extend({
      templateName: 'second',
      contentBinding: 'WHAT GOES HERE?'//how to bind to an object in an array
    })
  })
```

The problem is that it is not clear how to bind a view to a particular object in an ArrayController.

I have a jsFiddle illustrating the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/lifeinafolder/xUNUN/

For illustration purposes, the jsFiddle only has 2 states instead of all 6.

A similar problem is shown here: [Ember.js binding models stored within an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512568/ember-js-binding-models-stored-within-an-array). The solution is not very clear though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a computed property which returns an object at specific index, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/MUUs3/:

```js
App.ObjectAtBindable = Ember.Mixin.create({
    targetObject: function() {
        var objectIndex = this.get('objectIndex');
        var controller = this.get('controller');
        if (controller) {
            return controller.objectAt(objectIndex);
        }
        return null;
    }.property('controller', 'objectIndex').cacheable()
});

App.stateManager = Ember.StateManager.create({
    firstTab: Ember.ViewState.create({
        view: Ember.View.extend(App.ObjectAtBindable, {
            templateName: 'first',
            contentBinding: 'targetObject',
            controllerBinding: 'App.controller',
            objectIndex: 0
        })
    })
});
```